# Get pre-installed application and installed by user

Tags: android, installed-applications

I want to get pre-installed app (Like:- YouTube, Play store etc) And app installed by use.

But i am getting other applications also as shown in pic. how should i skip this applications.

Because YouTube is also system app and other app is also system app.

I want app like YouTube, Phone and Messaging storage,Naukari.com etc

[image: get other app also]

Comment: You can use below answer for pre-installed android app Pre-Installed Application Programtically https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253171

Comment: Since you haven't effectively described what apps you want and don't want, this is unanswerable.  For example, how would we know whether you want com.qrd.omadownload or not?  Or SampleExtAuthService?

Comment: @GabeSechan i describe in question that i want pre-installed app and app installed by user.mean app by vendor not system app but here YouTube is pre-installed app so  it showing as system App.

Comment: @DharmendraBhanushali THe OS doesn't make any such distinction between a "vendor app" (this term doesn't exist, you made it up) and another pre-installed app.  They're all system apps, because they're installed in the system directory where preinstalled apps go.  So if you want some subset of that, YOU have to come up with filtering criteria.

Comment: @GabeSechan than how does xender,ShareIt,AppLock get List of Application? And what is that filter criteria

Comment: We can't answer how another app does t it. My guess would be by filtering against a know list. But the only ones who can answer that is them

Comment: See my answer this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for Help. I get output as i need by following code.

```
private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);


    for (ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        String appName = pm.getApplicationLabel(app).toString();
        String packageName = app.packageName;
        Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(app);

        if(!packageName.equals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)) {
            if (pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName) != null) {

                res.add(new AppList(appName, packageName, icon));

            }
        }
    }
    if(res.size()>0){
       Collections.sort(res, new Comparator<AppList>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(AppList o1, AppList o2) {
               return o1.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));

           }
       });
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllVendorApp(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> apps= new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File[] systemFiles = new File("/system").listFiles();
            if (systemFiles != null) {
                for (File systemChild : systemFiles) {
                    if (systemChild.toString().contains("vendor") && systemChild.listFiles() != null) {
                        for (File vendorChild : systemChild.listFiles()) {
                            if (vendorChild.toString().contains("operator") && vendorChild.listFiles() != null) {
                                for (File operatorChild : vendorChild.listFiles()) {
                                    if (operatorChild.toString().contains("app") && operatorChild.listFiles() != null) {
                                        for (File operatorAppChild : operatorChild.listFiles()) {
                                            apps.add( operatorAppChild.toString().toLowerCase());

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logException(ex);
        }
        return apps;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and It is working fine for me.

In onCreate() of your activity

```
new LoadApplications().execute();
```

**Asynctask to get all the system applications in Android**

```
 private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ApplicationInfo>> {

        @Override
        protected List<ApplicationInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            systemAppsList = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            return systemAppsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ApplicationInfo> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setAdapter(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }


private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {

        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> systemAppsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {

                    boolean isSystemApp = ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
                    Log.i("SystemApps", info.packageName + ", isSystemApp=" + isSystemApp);

                    if (isSystemApp) {
                        systemAppsList.add(info);
                    } 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
         return systemAppsList;
    }


private void setAdapter(List<ApplicationInfo> result) {
        applicationAdapter = new ApplicationAdapter(getActivity(), systemAppsList);
        appListView.setAdapter(applicationAdapter);
    }
```